# div content padding based-on clip-path property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place some icons in a polygon div, issue is with the padding. the icons are cut down with polygon borders.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgba(176, 75, 80, 0.5);
}

#example {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align;
  center;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 0%, 83% 60%, 7% 82%);
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" />

<div id="container">
  <div id="example">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `padding: auto` but this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the flex layout , you may use `float` and `shape-outside`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside
> The shape-outside CSS property defines a shape—which may be non-rectangular—around which adjacent inline content should wrap. By default, inline content wraps around its margin box; shape-outside provides a way to customize this wrapping, making it possible to wrap text around complex objects rather than simple boxes.

Here is an average example you can inspire yourself from :

```css
  #container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgba(176, 75, 80, 0.5);
}

#example {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: justify;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 0%, 83% 60%, 7% 82%);
}

#example:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  shape-outside:  polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 25%, 0 45%, 7% 100%, 0 100%, 0 44%, 0 34%);
  }
  #example [data-shape]{
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 53% 40%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" />

<div id="container">
  <div id="example">
  <b data-shape></b>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-fw filled"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how the polygon of `shape-outside` is relatable with the polygon of `clip-path` because when I change the polygon of `clip-path`, it again behaves the same in the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadZakaria It is average, i did it by hand, but you can use https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ to help getting the right shape. First use a background and a clip-path to see your shape. once you have it, turn clip-path into shape-outside. shape-outside can also take an SVG or an image . Here his an example of mine using an  svg https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjbwvBe